# Swift: Ensure equivalence from different protocols with associated types

Tags: swift, generics, generic-programming, clean-architecture, associated-types

I am using the Clean Swift pattern for a project. That pattern aims to address the Massive View Controller problem that often comes with the MVC pattern.

The general idea states that a ViewController defers all logic that handles user interaction and general business logic to an Interactor. That Interactor does its thing, then sends the resulting data output to a Presenter. That Presenter wraps that data into a 'view model' and finally passes that back to the ViewController.

In order to implement this efficiently and allow for mocking, I decided to write protocols that my classes will need to adopt.

This will allow me to easily write very generic functions that a lot of view controllers need (like showing a spinner while loading, opening urls in a safari view, etc).

Essentially, my protocols are defined as such:

```
protocol CleanViewController: class {
    associatedType Interactor: CleanInteractor
    associatedType Router: CleanRouter
    init()
    init(interactor: Interactor, router: Router)
    var interactor: Interactor! { get set }
    var router: Router! { get set }
}

protocol CleanInteractor: class {
    associatedType Presenter: CleanPresenter
    init()
    init(presenter: Presenter)
    var presenter: Presenter! { get set }
}

protocol CleanPresenter: class {
    associatedType ViewController: CleanViewController
    init()
    init(viewController: ViewController)
    var viewController: ViewController? { get set }
}

protocol CleanRouter: class {
    associatedType DataStore: CleanDataStore
    associatedType ViewController: CleanViewController
    init()
    init(dataStore: DataStore, viewController: ViewController)
    var dataStore: DataStore! { get set }
    var viewController: ViewController? { get set }
}
```

So all of these are cross-referencing each other. This means that when I want to implement a new ViewController, I need to somehow link them all together. Right now this is done by always defining a `setup()` function, called from all of a UIViewController's initialisers.

Then, whenever I need to write up a new ViewController, for instance Login, this is how it would be implemented:

```
protocol LoginDisplayLogic: CleanViewController {
    func display(_ some: ViewModel)
}

class LoginViewController<Interactor: LoginBusinessLogic, Router: LoginRoutingLogic>: LoginDisplayLogic, UIViewController {
    var interactor: Interactor!

    func display(_ some: ViewModel) { // display something }
    @IBAction func userDidTapLoginButton(_ sender: Any) { interactor.login() }
}

protocol LoginBusinessLogic: CleanInteractor {
    func login()
}

protocol LoginDataStore: CleanDataStore {
    var email: String { get set }
    var password: String { get set }
}

class LoginInteractor<Presenter: LoginPresentationLogic>: LoginBusinessLogic, LoginDataStore {
    var presenter: Presenter!

    var email: String
    var password: String

    func login() {
        // do something with email & password
    }
}

protocol LoginPresentationLogic: CleanPresenter {
    func display(_ loginResult: Result)
}

class LoginPresenter<ViewController: LoginDisplayLogic>: LoginPresentationLogic {
    var viewController: ViewController?

    func display(_ loginResult: Result) { 
        // wrap the result to a viewModel and call the viewController
    }
}

protocol LoginRoutingLogic: CleanRouter {
    func route(to some: Where)
}

class LoginRouter<DataStore: LoginDataStore, ViewController: LoginDisplayLogic>: LoginRoutingLogic {
   func route(to some: Where) { // ... }
}
```

Now, I want to make this `setup()` function generic. Since each protocol defines its own associated types which all require an initialiser, I really just have to write it once.

So what I did was to write the following:

```
extension CleanViewController where 
    Interactor: CleanDataStore, 
    Interactor.Presenter.ViewController == Self, 
    Router.ViewController == Self, 
    Router.DataStore == Interactor {

    func setup() {
        let presenter = Interactor.Presenter(viewController: self)
        let interactor = Interactor(presenter: presenter)
        let router = Router(viewController: self, dataStore: interactor)
        self.interactor = interactor
        self.router = router
    }
}
```

But if then call this function from my LoginViewController, XCode raises the following compilation errors:

- `Referencing instance method 'setup()' on 'CleanViewController' requires the types 'LoginViewController<Interactor, Router>' and 'Router.ViewController' be equivalent`
- `Referencing instance method 'setup()' on 'CleanViewController' requires the types 'Interactor' and 'Router.DataStore' be equivalent`
- `Referencing instance method 'setup()' on 'CleanViewController' requires the types 'Router.ViewController' and 'Interactor.Presenter.ViewController' be equivalent`
- `Referencing instance method 'setup()' on 'CleanViewController' requires the types 'Router' and 'Interactor.Presenter.ViewController.Router.ViewController.Router' be equivalent`

which to me seems odd since the extension where `setup()` is declared should ensure that all these associated types are equivalent.

I know this post is a long & complex one, but what exactly am I missing here for this work?

Comment: I would suggest instead that you place this `setup()` in a Factory/Builder class instead of the `UIViewController`

Comment: I am not sure you will be able to initialize a `LoginViewController` given the circular dependency between the generic types. Do you really need the those to be generic?

Comment: @ZonilyJame I'm not familiar with the Factory concept, how would I approach this ?

Comment: @crom87 Yeah indeed the circular dependency makes it difficult... I need them to be generic so that I can inject mock classes for testing. I could avoid generic types and do something like `typealias Interactor = LoginBusinessLogic` but that then requires me to link the concrete type at some point anyway... 

Comment: @Skwiggs it means you would need to create a separate class to with the responsibility to instantiate these classes.

Comment: See this gist as an example https://gist.github.com/kuyazee/db6cb4bb38c69ba6d4465f811638030a